# Jenkins Groovy - accessing map elements

Tags: jenkins, groovy, docker-compose

I am trying to create docker-compose yaml file with Groovy:

```html
def depTemplate = [
                                version: "3.9", 
                                services:[
                                    "${serviceName}":[
                                        hostname: "some-hostname",
                                        environment: [],
                                        ports: [],
                                        volumes: [],
                                        restart: ''
                                ]
                            ]
            ]
```

I am trying to add some values to volumes:
**depTemplate.services."${serviceName}".volumes.add("some volume")**
but it fails with error **Cannot get property 'volumes' on null object**

Otherwise, if i declare template in following way:

```html
def depTemplate = [
                                version: "3.9", 
                                services:[
                                    application:[
                                        hostname: "some-hostname",
                                        environment: [],
                                        ports: [],
                                        volumes: [],
                                        restart: ''
                                ]
                            ]
            ]
```

and then trying to add new volume:  **depTemplate.services.application.volumes.add("some volume")** - it works perfectly.
Also when i am trying to get value from template by index:
print depTemplate.services[0] - it returns **null**, but when i am trying to get element by name: print depTemplate.services['application'] - it returns valid value:

{hostname=some-hostname, environment="some-environment-variables", ports="some-ports, volumes="some-volumes"  restart=}

So the question is how can i access map element by using variables and how can i access map elements by id?

Comment: service[serviceName].volume.add(...)

Answer (score 0):

```js
def depTemplate = [
   version: "3.9", 
   services:[
      (serviceName):[
         hostname: "some-hostname",
         environment: [],
         ports: [],
         volumes: [],
         restart: ''
      ]
   ]
]
depTemplate.service[serviceName].volume.add("asdf")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, still getting null when declaring service name with (serviceName) and trying to access field by depTemplate.service[serviceName] or set/add any value

Answer (score 0):

So i found my mistake - i missed another square brackets after services:

```
def depTemplate = [
   version: "3.9", 
   services:[
      [(serviceName):[
         hostname: "some-hostname",
         environment: [],
         ports: [],
         volumes: [],
         restart: ''
      ]]
   ]
]
depTemplate.service[0].volume.add("asdf")
```

So now i am able to access elements by index.